# Material-ui - cannot resolve module 'fbjs/lib/emptyFunction', 'fbjs/lib/invariant', 'fbjs/lib/warning'

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to use material-ui for a project. It throws the following error when using it:

[image]

I have tried going through the github repository for similar issues without any luck. Anyone has any ideas what might be the issue? I am adding the package.json file just in case its any of the dependencies screwing up.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "bidding",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Testing bidding application",
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "babel-node tools/startMessage.js",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel test:watch open:src lint:watch",
    "open:src": "babel-node tools/srcServer.js",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/esw webpack.config.* src tools",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "test": "mocha --reporter progress tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.test.js\"",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "clean-dist": "npm run remove-dist && mkdir dist",
    "remove-dist": "node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./dist",
    "build:html": "babel-node tools/buildHtml.js",
    "prebuild": "npm-run-all clean-dist test build:html",
    "build": "babel-node tools/build.js",
    "postbuild": "babel-node tools/distServer.js"
  },
  "author": "Supreet Singh",
  "license": "open",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "6.8.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "hashids": "^1.1.1",
    "j-i-c": "^2.0.2",
    "jquery": "2.2.3",
    "js-cookie": "^2.1.4",
    "material-ui": "^0.18.1",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.8",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^3.12.2",
    "react-redux": "4.4.5",
    "react-router": "2.4.0",
    "react-router-redux": "4.0.4",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "redux": "3.5.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.0",
    "redux-localstorage": "0.4.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.0.1",
    "tether": "1.3.7",
    "toastr": "2.1.2",
    "uuid-js": "^0.7.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.8.0",
    "babel-core": "6.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-display-name": "2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
    "babel-register": "6.8.0",
    "cheerio": "0.22.0",
    "colors": "1.1.2",
    "compression": "1.6.1",
    "cross-env": "1.0.7",
    "css-loader": "0.23.1",
    "enzyme": "2.2.0",
    "eslint": "2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "1.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "5.0.1",
    "eslint-watch": "2.1.11",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "0.9.6",
    "expect": "1.19.0",
    "express": "4.13.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "0.8.5",
    "jsdom": "8.5.0",
    "mocha": "2.4.5",
    "nock": "8.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "1.8.0",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.0.2",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "1.2.3",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.0.2",
    "rimraf": "2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.6.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.10.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/supreetsingh247/bidding"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`npm install --save fbjs` worked for me (with `material-ui==0.18.1`).

It looks like they missed a dependency (which seems to have been [removed](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/commit/4f8718846c2d348cd9ad3acb054e1b77bd3cd10c?diff=split) in `master`). Hopefully next time that `material-ui` is updated, we'll be able to remove the explicit dependency on `fbjs` and go on our way.